# Ubuntu 20.04, have broken python3, can it be fixed?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, python3

Realise this is a common problem, all my fault.
now have in /usr/bin

```
/usr/bin/python3 -> /python3.8       (in red)
/usr/bin/pyenve -> pyvenv-3.8        (in red)
```

no amount of fiddling with apt or synaptice et. al seems to fix it.  Is there a way to reinstall default python 3.8 and get this working outwith a full reinstall?  Thx. J

Comment: pyemve is not by default installed. python3 is a link to the current python3.. version in the same dir (usr/bin)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the issue in the future, you can use python virtual environments for your coding and leave the ubuntu system stuff alone.

You will have your own python environment, used only by you, fully under your control, and you will know what's happening with it at all times. Instead of the system possibly updating the modules you are trying to use in your code.

- https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: ..and then the code breaks when it goes anywhere else. Virtual environments are a mixed blessing.